# WebView2: does COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_ERROR_STATUS_UNKNOWN mean a server side error?

Tags: webview2

When a server-side error occurs, what will webview's NavigationCompleted event give for the status?

Will it be `COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_ERROR_STATUS_UNKNOWN`? If so can I then use `ICoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs2` to get the HTTP status code?

How about for the few specific ones mentioned in status descriptions, like 401 or 407?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_ERROR_STATUS_UNKNOWN means all error except from the ones listed in the doc below. So the local error can be included also.

Also, when the navigation is success, the value is unknown.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2?view=webview2-1.0.1293.44#corewebview2_web_error_status

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2navigationcompletedeventargs?view=webview2-1.0.1293.44

Comment: Thank you, but thats kind of evident from the descriptions. The important part is what status is given for server-side errors such as (say) 404. I've re-worded my question to clarify.